# There are no components in Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.dll

Tags: uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I'm having trouble to add the components of the UWP Community Toolkit to the Toolbox.

What I've tried so far:
- create a new tab
- in that tab 'select items'
- choose UWP tab in pop-up
- browse to folder with Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.dll
C:\Users\xxx.nuget\packages\microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls\2.2.0\lib\uap10.0
- choose dll, open

ERROR : there are no componints in ...

- updated VS2017 to latest version
- reboot
- Installed de Win10 SDK
- reboot

No change

- reset toolbox
  NO change
- Drag-dropping dll in toolbox does not work eather.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a guide available [here in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/toolbox-support), but it is guided to pre-2.0 version of UWP Community Toolkit. In later versions, the controls should appear in the toolbox automatically.

Please try to install the package in an empty solution, rebuild and check if the toolbox is populated with the controls. In case it is not, I would suggest trying a Visual Studio repair.

Comment: That was the manual I followed. They actually doe appear (now) in the toolbar, maybe because they do by default and maybe that is the reason I got the error because there were no EXTRA / NEW components to add.